# How to set my java library to be used in desktop application and Android App

Tags: java, android, annotations

Is there any method (preferred an annotation) to find if my library was used in Desktop Application or Android App, Wherein I have a method that works fine in Desktop Apps, but in Android Apps it just works for API Level 19 and above, so when I typed `@TargetApi(19)` on the function it cause an ERROR while `@TargetApi()` is not found in Desktop Application. Is there any function to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) { ... }` in your Android Apps for calling the functions that are dependent on Api 19+